# How to Access dynamic string value in C++ by JavaScript in CEF3?

Tags: javascript, c++, chromium-embedded

I'm making desktop application by CEF3 and I'm building function that take file path and read it into buffer and this work fine to me but I don't know how JavaScript take the value of the file that I read
EX : 
C++ code : 
string fileContent = readFile(URL);
I need to send fileContent to JavaScript variable

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is connection to C++? If you want to read files with JavaScript then there is an API for this. Please check this out http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: thank you for your response ,I need to load large files more than 200 MB so  when I load,I need to  make operation in data that extracted from the file in the same time of loading it so using C++ give me more power to do that

Comment: As far as I know: At least for Windows platform there is a way to use COM objects to extend the abilities of JavaScript. This would apply if you try to read files from a browser under windows. What exactly you want to do? It has to run server or client site?

Answer (score 2):

Normally you should use javascript bindings to communicate between c++<>js, see the [Javascript Integration](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/JavaScriptIntegration.md) wiki page. However since this is huge amount of data, for performance reasons it is best to send it via request, see [this topic](http://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=10590):

> If the amount of binary data is large perform a request (via
>   XMLHttpRequest, for example) that is then handled using a custom
>   scheme handler or CefRequestHandler::GetResourceHandler().

Comment: thank you for our response,please can you  attached me sample of JavaScript and C++ code that more illustrate the idea

Comment: @AbdoSalah see the Javascript Integration wiki page for example code